# Is 2^2n = O(2^n)?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I am learning algorithm analysis. While doing the theory I across many big-O proofs. I was able to solve them but I need help with omega which is the oposite of big-O?

Is 2<sup>2n</sup> = O(2<sup>n</sup>)? --->My answer is NO

I need help to understand these
Is 2<sup>2n</sup> = ω(2^n)?

What about n<sup>c</sup> = ω(c^n)?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem set question, so I'll provide some hints but not go into complete proofs.

As a hint for whether 2<sup>2n</sup> = ω(2<sup>n</sup>), try evaluating

> lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (2<sup>n</sup> / 2<sup>2n</sup>).

If you can show that this is 0, then you've proven that 2<sup>n</sup> = o(2<sup>2n</sup>) and therefore that 2<sup>2n</sup> = ω(2<sup>n</sup>).

As for whether n<sup>c</sup> = = ω(c<sup>n</sup>), think about the following cases: what happens if c < 1, and what happens if c > 1?

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am getting NO for "2^2n = O(2^n)" 

so for  2^2n = omega(2^n) --> 2^n=O(2^2n) also the answer is No. isnt it? as n is unbounded

Comment: Also for the second part. supppose i assume c=2.

then 2^n=O(n^2) now limit n-->infinity will give me a non zero value..so this is also false? please confirm

Comment: Here's another hint on the 2^2n problem - can you simplify the expression 2^2n? Also, do you have any intuition about the growth rate of 2^n versus n^2?